# Catching thrown Enum Values

Tags: haxe

Haxe permits the throwing of pretty much anything, but seems to be a bit limited in its catching ability. For example, I have a static error function that throws values of an ErrorType enum:

```
class Error 
{
    public static var CATCH_ALL:Bool = false;
    public static function Throw(aError:ErrorType, ?ignore:Bool=false, ?inf:PosInfos):Void
    {
        trace('Error: $aError at ' + inf.className + ':' + inf.methodName + ':' + inf.lineNumber);
        if (!CATCH_ALL && !ignore)
        {
            throw aError;
        }
    }
}

enum ErrorType 
{
    NULL_PARAM(msg:String);
    NOT_FOUND(msg:String);
}
```

While I can catch pretty much anything, I am limited to basic types, class types and enum types. This means that I can catch every string, but not specifically a string containing "potato", for example. If I create multiple error classes, I can catch a specific class type while ignoring the others, but the same thing seems not to be possible with enum. Would there be an alternative to the following code that would compile?

```
try
{
    Error.Throw(ErrorType.NULL_PARAM('Potato'));
}
catch (e:ErrorType.NULL_PARAM) trace(e); //does not work nor compile
catch (e:ErrorType) trace(e); //works, but catches every error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selection of `catch`-expressions is [limited to types](https://haxe.org/manual/expression-try-catch.html) / doesn't provide pattern matching capabilities like `switch` does:

> Catch blocks are checked from top to bottom with the first one whose **type is compatible** with the thrown value being picked.

All *values* of the `ErrorType` enum are compatible with the `ErrorType` *type*. This means that unfortunately, I think the best you can do is to catch `ErrorType` and then do the selection inside the catch-block, using a `switch` and potentially re-throwing it. However, note that a simple `throw e` would currently cause the stack trace to be lost as discussed in [#4159](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/4159).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I lose the stack trace if I rethrow an error. I could instead include the PosInfos in the error object to at least keep position data even without the stack. OR simply go back to my old way of having an error object and extended classes for every type of error. Since I read somewhere that enum values with parameters were similar to classes in code generation I kind of hoped they could act as unique types.

Comment: Note that you can preserve the call stack on some platforms - e.g. on Neko there's [`neko.Lib.rethrow`](http://api.haxe.org/neko/Lib.html#rethrow), as mentioned in that issue.